# How to upsert MongoCollection but keep some values?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, collections

*Hi,
I don't know how to put a good title for it but I'm sure you will understand*

So I'm trying to set 2 fields on my Mongo collection when the user click on a button BUT every 60sc I have a method that is running and who make that:

```
  upsertCollectionMachines = Meteor.bindEnvironment(function() {
      machinesCount = 0;
        var protocol;
        var port;
        Machine.list({
            inspect: true
        }, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, machines) {
            if (typeof machines === "undefined") {
                console.error("Impossible to access 'machines' from 'Machine.list:  '" + err);
            } else {
                machines.forEach(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(machineInfo) {
                    machinesCount += 1;
                    if (machineInfo.url != null) {
                        var urlToArray = machineInfo.url.split(":")
                        port = urlToArray[urlToArray.length - 1];
                        protocol = "https";
                    } else {
                        port = "2376";
                        protocol = "https";
                    }
                    InfosMachines.upsert({
                        nameMachine: machineInfo.name,
                    }, {
                        nameMachine: machineInfo.name,
                        stateMachine: machineInfo.state,
                        ipAddr: machineInfo.driver.ipAddress,
                        port: port,
                        protocol: protocol
//here I want to add isUsed: false,  
//whoUseIt: "", but I think if I set isUsed true --> after 60s it will be false again right ?
                    });
                }));
                if (apiKeyGenerated == false) {
                    getTheAPIKeyGrafana(function(err, res) {
                        if (!err) {
                            apiKeyGenerated = true;
                            updateDashboard();
                        } else {
                            console.error(err);
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                  updateDashboard();
                }
            }
        }));
    })
```

Where the important part is the `InfosMachines.upsert()`. Now I want to set 2 fields like this :

```
'lockTheMachine': function(nameMachine, nameUser){
        InfosMachines.upsert({
            nameMachine: nameMachine,
        }, {
            nameMachine: nameMachine,
            isUsed: true,
            whoUseIt: nameUser
        });
        //upsertCollectionMachines();
        console.log(nameUser +" has locked the machine: " + nameMachine);
        },
```

But first it doesn't look likes it add the 2fields to the collection and secondly the 60s interval method will delete them right ?

Thank you for the help

Comment: I have an idea, I'll let this thread open but my idea is to create a 2nd collection for used machines

Comment: Hi Jerome; when you say it doesn't look like it adds the 2 fields, can you show exactly how you expected the data to end up, and to what it was actually updated?

Comment: @VinceBowdren I do it tomorrow and I poke you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a little hard to follow exactly what you are trying to do in your question, but I think I got the main gist of it.

Basically, you want the `lockTheMachine()` function upsert to only ever set `nameMachine`, `isUsed`, and `whoUseIt` fields and you only want `upsertCollectionMachines()` to set `stateMachine`, `ipAddr`, `port`, `protocol` fields on update and only set `isUsed` and `whoUseIt` to default values on insert?

You should be able to do that using the below upserts.

Use this upsert inside your `upsertCollectionMachines()` function.

```
InfosMachines.upsert({
  nameMachine: machineInfo.name,
}, {
  $set: {
    stateMachine: machineInfo.state,
    ipAddr: machineInfo.driver.ipAddress,
    port: port,
    protocol: protocol
  },
  $setOnInsert: {
    isUsed: false,
    whoUseIt: "",
  }
});
```

It will always set `stateMachine`, `ipAddr`, `port`, `protocol` fields regardless if it is inserting or updated, but will only modify `isUsed` and `whoUseIt` if it is inserting (therefore, it will not overwrite the values set from the other function).

Use this upsert inside your `lockTheMachine()` function.

```
InfosMachines.upsert({
  nameMachine: nameMachine,
}, {
  $set: {
    isUsed: true,
    whoUseIt: nameUser
  }
});
```

It will only ever insert or update those 2 specific fields (`isUsed` and `whoUseIt`).

Now, why does this work?  First, we are using [update operator expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#id1) (instead of only `field:value` expressions) which allow you to only update specific fields when needed and using `$setOnInsert` ensures that we only ever modify those fields on insert only.  Note, that if the upsert determines it needs to insert a new document, per the [mongodb upsert option behavior](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-behavior), it creates a new document using...

> The fields and values of both the `<query>` and `<update>` parameters if the `<update>` parameter contains update operator expressions

This means you don't have to ever actually `$set` the `nameMachine` field explicitly in the update expression.

Comment: Hi, first thank you it's the best answer I've ever get ! Your explanations are very great ! The collection is updated as I wanted to so it's perfect :)